# Is running rsync as root problematic?

Tags: malware, linux, exploit, vulnerability, root

Is there a security risk with running rsync as root to copy potentially malicious files? Or for that matter with any read command like cp, cat, du?

**Background:**
I'm moving data from various systems onto my new proxmox host (could be any debian based distro) for centralized storage. So I plugged the hdds into my new server and mounted them read-only to copy all files over to my new storage array with rsync. Among this data are files of family members which I don't control and that could have been compromised (not likely but possible).

Is there a problem here or am I way too paranoid?

Answer (score 0):

If you care about preserving file owner, group, permissions, etc. you have no choice but to run `rsync` as root.  If you don't have access to the directories they store their files in, you'll also need to use the superuser account.  If you do have access to the files and use `rsync` as your non-admin user, it will change your user to the owner/group for those files.

I recommend running rsync as root using the `-a` to preserve the owner, group, permissions, etc.

If you use `rsync` correctly, even if the files were compromised, you wouldn't change the situation you're currently in.  If you don't use `-a` or a combination of other switches you could be creating a security problem, and you will definitely be creating a sysadmin problem.